# adding a sequence to an animation and then playing it backwards when button is click with reanimated

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-reanimated-v2

I have an animation running but I would like to add a animated scale to it before the rest happens. I would also like to be able to click a button to reset the animation to original values with it animating.

I have a bit of code that handles multiple different animations on images like so :

EntryAnimation.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Animated, {
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  useDerivedValue,
  interpolate,
  withDelay,
  withTiming,
  withSpring,  
  Easing,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
   
export const EntryAnimation = ({
  children,
  index, 
  rotateV, 
  scaleV,
  offsetXV, 
  offsetYX,
}) => { 
  const play = useSharedValue(play);
  const progress = useDerivedValue(() => {
    return play.value 
      ? withDelay(50 * (index ?? 0), withSpring(1, { duration: 350 }))   
      : 0; 
  });
  
  useEffect(() => {
    play.value = play;
  }, []);

  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    // const opacity = interpolate(progress.value, [0, 1], [0, 1]);
    const translateY = interpolate(progress.value, [0, 1], [0, offsetYX]);
    const translateX = interpolate(progress.value, [0, 1], [0, offsetXV]);
    const rotate = interpolate(progress.value, [0, 1], [0, rotateV]);
    const scale = interpolate(progress.value, [0, 1], [1, scaleV]);

    return {
      transform: [{ translateY }, { translateX }, { rotate }, { scale }],
    };
  });

  return <Animated.View style={animatedStyle}>{children}</Animated.View>;
};
```

These are triggered with a click and the values to change are set like so in my App.js

```
<EntryAnimation
                      index={2}
                      rotateV={-0.25}
                      scaleV={0.6}
                      offsetXV={190}
                      offsetYX={-280}>
                      <Animated.Image
                        source={{ uri: item.poster }}
                        style={[styles.posterImage]}
                      />
                    </EntryAnimation>
```

It works a treat but like I said I simply cannot add a sequence that shrinks the image before the rest takes place and when another button is clicked it animates back to original. I have tried various ways but nothing remotely works?

Can it be done or am I just wasting my time this way? Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks
Jules